# Правильно ли сказать "проспал на работу"?

Tags: грамматика, предлоги, управление

Правильно ли сказать "проспал на работу"? Или единственно правильный вариант "проспал работу"?

Answer (score 3):

- Если рассматривать с позиции литературного языка, то верно будет
  только ***проспал и опоздал на работу***.
- Если использовать разговорный стиль, то допустимо: ***проспал
  работу*** или ***проспал подъём на работу***.

Пояснение — в БТС имеется два интересующих нас значения слова "проспал":

> - Проснуться позже, чем нужно. "Проспал и опоздал на лекцию".
> - *кого-что*. ***Разг.*** (выделение моё — N.) Находясь в состоянии сна, пропустить. "Проспал свой поезд".

Второе значение — разговорное, поэтому и использовать его можно, если только допустим в вашем случае разговорный стиль.

Изредка оборот "проспал на работу" встречается у авторитетных авторов, например:

> Прощались так долго, что я проспал на работу (Юрий Поляков "100 дней
> до приказа", 1987).

Но это единичные случаи, на которые, на мой взгляд, вряд ли следует ориентироваться.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133619/discussion-on-answer-by-nektoid------).

Answer (score 3):

> Правильно ли сказать "проспал на работу"?

По-моему, бо́льшая часть русскоговорящего населения из числа опаздывающих на работу именно так и говорит…

Из современного учебного пособия для иностранцев, изучающих русский язык:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]